# Slow performance on FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a API controller action that returns large file 400+ mb.
Right now i am using a FileStreamResult as IActionResult, which is very slow on the larger files around +900mb but works on files around 4gb.

```
[HttpGet("{fileId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(Guid fileId)
    {
        var fileResponse = await _bus.RequestAsync<FileRequest, FileResponse>(new FileRequest(fileId));
        var file = new FileInfo(@"c:\users\peter\desktop\save\" + fileId.ToString());
        return new FileStreamResult(file.OpenRead(), fileResponse.ContentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileResponse.Filename
        };
    }
```

If i copy the file to a memorystream first it is much faster but then i got a limitation and it fails at 4gb files.

```
[HttpGet("{fileId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(Guid fileId)
    {
        var fileResponse = await _bus.RequestAsync<FileRequest, FileResponse>(new FileRequest(fileId));
        var file = new FileInfo(@"c:\users\peter\desktop\save\" + fileId.ToString());
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        file.OpenRead().CopyTo(ms);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, fileResponse.ContentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileResponse.Filename
        };
    }
```

How can i return large files fast thru the MVC Api?

Comment: Good question. There are multiple solutions on SO already. What did you use in the final solution?